# Removing the motor from a 2.5" HDD for controls project

Tags: motor, stepper-motor

I have a project that requires an extremely high rotation rate motor, and I have a 2.5" HDD that I'd like to take the motor out of. I chose a 2.5" HDD for lightweighting reasons and for the drive platter size.

Upon disassembly, I discovered that the motor was mounted with a press fit or epoxy. The method of mounting was something I had neglected to consider, but fortunately I didn't purchase a *new* HDD for this experiment.

I have access to a milling machine and can cut the motor out, along with a built-in mounting bracket, but this would be tedious and I don't really want to do this. **Does anyone know whether it is possible to extract a usable motor of this type from the HDD casing? If it is possible, how?**

Alternatively, if anyone knows where I can find pre-balanced motor/disk combinations that can hit 10+ kRPM without breaking the bank, I'd be extremely interested in learning where such things exist.

Comment: most hard drives spin at around 7200 rpm ... not sure if the motor can be pushed higher

Comment: @jsotola I was careful to purchase a 15,000 rpm HDD.